# unable to send mail using JvMail

Tags: delphi, jedi

JvMail1 is a vcl component from project Jedi.

The code is pretty straightforward :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
JvMail1.Clear;
JvMail1.Recipient.AddRecipient('admin@whatever.si');
JvMail1.Subject := edit1.Text;
JvMail1.Body.Text:= memo2.Text;
JvMail1.SendMail;
end;
```

Upon clicking send button,this triggers the opening of my default mail client (outlook 2010)
After clicking 'send' from outlook, mail soon returns undelivered:

> > The following recipient(s) cannot be reached:'admin@whatever.si ...   None of your e-mail accounts could send to this recipient.

However if I send the mail from Outlook itself using the same adress it gets delivered without a problem. Is this a problem with Outlook or ???
Also, is there a way of directly sending mail without the Outlook interference ?

Comment: Didnt use the component for a very long time. I will try the answer from there.

Comment: yes, the answer i.e solution si the right one. Only the mystery remains as to why smtp: is needed before the actual adress.